# Transform the equation of $z(x,y)$ into an equation of $w(u.v)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

$$
z_{xx} - 2z_{xy} + z_{yy} = 0
$$
Transform the equation of $z(x,y)$ into an equation of $w(u.v)$, where $w = \frac{z}{x}$ and 
$$
u = x + y
$$
$$
v = \frac{y}{x}
$$
Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Use the Chain Rule?

Comment: Why are you using $z''_{xx}$? Simply writing $z_{xx}$ specifies that you are taking the second derivative of the function $z$ with respect to $x$..

Comment: @Don Surely. But is there a better way to do this (perhaps massage the equation a bit before applying the chain rule)? Applying chain rule on both side is rather tedious.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "both sides". My approach would simply be to find the partials of $w$, $u$, and $v$, and plug them into your Chain Rule expansion of $z(x,y)$ to get an expression with respect to your new variables.

Comment: Factor:

$$
z_{xx}-2z_{xy}+z_{yy}=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2z.
$$

Now determine how to express $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ (and their partials of course).

Comment: @Don Do you mean find partials of $w, u, v$ with respect to $x, y$? But the problem needs a equation about $w(u, v)$  so there won't be $x$ and $y$

Comment: @user3 That looks like a good start! After I find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, how do I convert them into a equation involving only $w(u, v)$, which is $z(x(u, v), y(u, v)) / x(u,v)$ ?

Comment: @leafpile write $z=wx$ and use the product rule.